# Is there any wayt to use Point together with Double?

Tags: java, class, constructor, point

I want to use Point to make the console spit out some given coordinates in another class, but it seems Point is not compatible with double if I understand the error messages I am getting right. Is there anyway to get around this?

```java
package Stad;

import java.awt.*;

public class Stad {

    private String namn;
    private int antal;
    private Point koordinater;

    public Stad(String namn, int antal, double x, double y){
        this.namn = namn;
        this.antal = antal;
        Point xy = new Point(x, y);
        this.koordinater = xy;
    }
    public String getNamn(){
        return namn;
    }

    public int getAntal(){
        return antal;
    }
    public Point getKoordinater(){
        return koordinater;
    }

    public String getInfo(){
        String info = "Stad: " + this.getNamn()
                + "\nAntal invånare: " + this.getAntal()
               + "\nKoordinater: " + this.getKoordinater();
        return info;
    }

}
```

Comment: How about Point2D.Double ?

Comment: [Point2D](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) is a super class of Point. You could use the double version, or you can cast your double values to int, if you don't need the double information.

Comment: `Point` is part of the java.awt package, containg the "Abstract Window Toolkit", so it was introduced to represent screen coordinates. It was never meant to be used for geographic coordinates (meaning latitude/longitude). You might get away with using `Point2D.Double` if you just want to display the values (no computations).

Comment: I am gonna try your suggestion just to get the satisfaction of seeing it work, but further a down the road I do want to calculate distances, you say Point2D.Double is not suitable for this? why? And what are my options?

Comment: ah yes update: It worked with Point2D.Double even tho the output was a bit ugly. Maybe its better I build my own method. 

Stad: Hogvallastrand
Antal invånare: 1275
Koordinater: Point2D.Double[29.53, 12.81]

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score -1):

this is the new code with Point2D.Double incorporated

````java
package Stad;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Stad {

    private String namn;
    private int antal;
    private Point2D.Double koordinater;

    public Stad(String namn, int antal, double x, double y){
        this.namn = namn;
        this.antal = antal;
        Point2D.Double xy = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        this.koordinater = xy;
    }
    public String getNamn(){
        return namn;
    }

    public int getAntal(){
        return antal;
    }
    public Point2D.Double getKoordinater(){
        return koordinater;
    }

    public String getInfo(){
        String info = "Stad: " + this.getNamn()
                + "\nAntal invånare: " + this.getAntal()
               + "\nKoordinater: " + this.getKoordinater();
        return info;
    }

}```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).